# Need help in clearly defining a product of primes and their powers

Tags: functions, prime-numbers, factorial

I am looking for a clear mathematical way to describe the product of the minimum set of primes and their powers that are contained within a sequence of consecutive integers.

For example, in the sequence: $2,3,...,10$, this product is $2^33^25^17^1= 2520$

For the sequence $20,21,22,23,24,25$, this would be $2^33^15^27^1(11)^123^1$

Let $x$ be the first integer in the sequence and $n$ be the number of consecutive integers.

Let $v_p(x,n)$ be the highest power of $p$ that divides $x+i$ where $0 \le i < n$

Would this be a clear way of describing this product:

$$\prod\limits_{p | \frac{(x+n-1)!}{(x-1)!}} p^{v_p(x,n)}$$

I ask because I am trying to analyze an intuition I have that:

$$\frac{(x+n-1)!}{(x-1)!} \div \prod\limits_{p | \frac{(x+n-1)!}{(x-1)!}} p^{v_p(x,n)} \le (n-1)! $$

I have a question about this relationship and don't want to waste anyone's time if I can't state the relationship clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for a way to describe the product using mathematical notation ?
If so, as far as I can tell there is nothing wrong with your representation.

Also note that you can write your product as :

$\frac{(x+n-1)!}{(x-1)!} \div \prod\limits_{p | \frac{(x+n-1)!}{(x-1)!}} p^{v_p(x,n)} \le \Gamma (n)$

Comment: Thanks very much for confirming!  I appreciate the suggestion about the gamma function.  That's the better way to go!  :-)